# WEKA - ClassNotFoundException on Android

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, svm, weka

I've built a `MultiClassClassifier` with the option SMO in Weka GUI and used a `MultilayerPerceptron` as the calibration method. I've tested the model from  Eclipse (Java) on multiple samples and it works really well on my PC. When I try and use the same classifier on Android I get an error that is caused by:

> Didn't find
>   class:"weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron$ControlPanel"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/mypackage.myapp/base.apk,nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,system/lib]]
>   at
>   Dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)

I use the same Java library of Weka (v3.8) in my Eclipse Android project and in my Java Eclipse project. It works well on Android if I don't use the MultilayerPerceptron for calibration but the results aren't as good as the ones from a calibrated classifier. I've also turned the GUI option OFF in Weka GUI and it doesn't help.

**Here are the base configuration settings for my classifier in Weka GUI:** `weka.classifiers.meta.MultiClassClassifier -M 0 -R 2.0 -S 1 -W weka.classifiers.functions.SMO -- -C 1.0 -L 0.001 -P 1.0E-12 -N 0 -M -V -1 -W 1 -K "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.PolyKernel -E 1.0 -C 250007" -calibrator "weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -L 0.3 -M 0.2 -N 500 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H a"`

**MultiClassClassifier settings:**

[image]

**SMO settings:**

[image]

**MultilayerPerceptron settings:**

[image]

1. **[SOLVED]** Does this mean I can't use the MultilayerPerceptron as a calibration method on Android?
2. **[SOLVED]** Can I build a classifier with the MultilayerPerceptron without the ControlPanel part?
3. **[SOLVED]** Is there a workaround in Weka settings or some other to avoid this?

I've managed to obtain some info on the situation from the Weka mailing-list and it seems there really isn't an easy solution to work with the MultiLayerPerceptron in a MultiClassClassifier for Android usage. Since the MultilayerPerceptron class uses the Java .awt package that isn't fully supported by Android, there is another possible solution.

Weka has another classifier called the MLPClassifier (MultiLayerPerceptronClassifier) that hasn't got a GUI. This seems 
to be the easiest workaround so far.